# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [853, 854]

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, prediction

I am working on a classification task. I got this error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [853, 854].

854 is the size of `y_pred` and 853 is the size of `y_true`. I don't know why the size of `y_true` not the same as `y_pred`. Although the size of `validation_data` which is the input to get `y_pred` and `y_true` is 854.

I got the error in this line:

```
tp,fp,tn,fn = perf_measure(y_true,y_pred)
```

I don't know how to solve this error, any help would be appreciated.

I am working for 4 days to solve this error.

Here is the code:

```
def generate_y_true(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):
    y_true = []
    from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
    to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
    for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
        f=paths[i]
        x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
        x = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(x, axis=0), axis = 0)
        x = x.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)
        if('P' in f):
            y_true.extend([1]*x.shape[0])
        else:
            y_true.extend([0]*x.shape[0])
    return y_true

def perf_measure(y_actual, y_hat):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

    for i in range(len(y_hat)): 
        if y_actual[i]==y_hat[i]==1:
           TP += 1
        if y_hat[i]==1 and y_actual[i]!=y_hat[i]:
           FP += 1
        if y_actual[i]==y_hat[i]==0:
           TN += 1
        if y_hat[i]==0 and y_actual[i]!=y_hat[i]:
           FN += 1
    return(TP, FP, TN, FN)

y_true = generate_y_true(indexPat, validation_data)

tp,fp,tn,fn=perf_measure(y_true,y_pred)
```

Comment: It's a little bit hard to debug this error, while you only post one function of whole code. It's better the error be reproducible. However, if it's too much, you should share at least which line leads to the error, and every information from your code that may be related.

Comment: @Kaveh I got the error in this line `tp,fp,tn,fn=perf_measure(y_true,y_pred)`. I have edited my post. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot have a greater overview of the code, I suspect that the error comes from here:

```
 from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
 to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
```

It is likely that you miss an index (853 instead of 854) with this sort of division and instead of 854 you get 853.

At the same time in this for loop:

```
for i in range(from_, int(to_))
```

remember that you do not reach the upper limit interval `int(to_)`, the for loop loops up until `int(to_)-1`.

I hope it helps you solve your problem.